# ZF2 how to change locale in the view

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-translate

my config is

```
'translator' => array(
'locale' => 'en_EN',
'translation_file_patterns' => array(
    array(
        'type'     => 'gettext',
        'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

and how i can change locale from my view or controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch the `Translator` instance and invoke the `setLocale()` method. Example (controller context):

```
// Get the translator from the service locator.
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$translator->setLocale($myLocale);
```

Comment: I think code should be like this $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');

Comment: This works fine but only when the value of `$myLocale` variable is `en_US` or in case of french - `fr_FR`. I would like to know what should I do if the value is just `fr`. My url is `domain.com/fr/..`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

```
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$translator->setLocale($myLocale);
```